# VB.NET Grab URL From Webbrowser1

Tags: vb.net

How can i grab this url and paste it in a textbox?

Logout (Kassy Daniels) · Help

from this in webbrowser1

i want it to grab the /logout.php? url cause each user is different

and just paste it in a textbox1 when you hit a button

Comment: Please clarify with a better example.

Comment: On the mobile site of facebook there a logout button in text i want the button to paste the text of that certin logout link into textbox1 and the browser is inside of the program also

Comment: Do you know the ID of this button?

Comment: Its not a button its a link... with text heres a pic http://i56.tinypic.com/n1qqo4.png
Look at that t he html for it is above in my post

The BUTTON i want it where you PRESS the button on the FORM it will grab the link and paste it in a textbox1

Comment: Were you able to get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your webbrowser is `WebBrowser1`,

Using `WebBrowser1.Document.Links` will get you a `HTMLElementCollection` of all of the links on the page.

You can iterate through those, and check the `OuterHtml` element of each of those links (which will give you a string that contains the raw link, the IDs, etc.) for the text your are looking for (in this case `logout?`).

Using the substring command, extract that URL, and eliminate the surrounding text, and you can plug that right into the textbox.

Update: Using Firebug or your favorite DOM tool, you can find that the logout link is in the root div of the document

```
    Dim rootDiv As HtmlElement = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("root")
    Dim links As HtmlElementCollection = rootDiv.GetElementsByTagName("a")
    Dim index As Integer
    For i As Integer = 0 To links.Count - 1
        If links(i).InnerHtml.Contains("Logout") Then
            index = i
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i

    Dim stringofLink As String = links(index).OuterHtml
```

If the page changes in structure, this should be somewhat resilient to it, but you may need to generalize it further.  Process stringofLink however you want to break it up (find the ampersand that you need and then copy from the question mark to that point).

Comment: It appears to be more complex than that because the logout link is not in the first level of links - I have checked down to four levels deep and not found it.

Comment: @Matt It's possible.  I do not have access to the mobile Facebook site to test this, but in general, the steps I laid out will get the job done.  There may be some minor obfuscation put in by the site authors to discourage people from this type of activity, I do not know.

Comment: Jonsca you can go to http://m.facebook.com

Comment: @Kassy I brought up the site, and I don't see where that link is on the page.

Comment: @jonsca - the log out is at the bottom right of the window (you have to be logged in to see it)

Comment: @Matt m.facebook wasn't rendering correctly in Chrome, I had to open it in IE before I could see the link

Comment: @Matt I think what I have now works