# Facebook Logout and Like

Tags: c#, vb.net, facebook, authentication, logout

I am new to VB.net and making a facebook windows app. I am doing just few simple things like login, log out and like a page. 
I was able to login in FB by using help from http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vbgeneral/thread/94a8ce89-2318-4b14-9915-58f95ce58485

But now am stuck at log out and liking a page. I am using m.facebook.com so to keep my coding easy understandable and convenient.

Please tell me how to log out and like a page.

facebook uses a logout key that i am unable to extract from the page. And like is also creating some problem as there is no ID, so i cant use getelementbyid

thanks for help

Comment: Nithing wrong with browsers. But to do experiments and learn new things, i am doing this

Comment: Possible duplicate [VB.NET Grab URL From Webbrowser1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6956566/vb-net-grab-url-from-webbrowser1/6957614#6957614)

Comment: Incidentally, this would make far more sense to do using the Facebook developer api.  Using it you get a token the first time the user logs in and you simply request any privelages you need to work (and offline access if you want to avoid login every time), then there is a simple .net api for making syncronous & asyncronous calls to like pages etc.

Answer (score 0):

If someone is facing the same problem, here is the solution:

Facebook Logout:

```
Dim allelements As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.All

    For Each webpageelement As HtmlElement In allelements

        If webpageelement.GetAttribute("data-sigil") = "logout" Then

            WebBrowser1.Navigate(webpageelement.GetAttribute("href"))

        End If

    Next
```

Facebook Page Like:

```
 Dim allelements As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.All

    For Each webpageelement As HtmlElement In allelements

        If webpageelement.GetAttribute("value") = "Like" Then

            webpageelement.InvokeMember("click")                

        End If
    Next
```