# Webbrowser not opening pages in series vb.net

Tags: vb.net, browser, webbrowser-control

I am new to programming and making a app in VB.net

I have asked a ques before (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6989042/facebook-logout-and-like)

Now I have new ques. I am trying to make an app that login's in FB page writes on wall or like a page and logs out. I want to do this in series but I am not able to do that.

So i tried to do some debugging and found the problem. Its that complier is moving too fast, before its able to login, logout link is activates.

So i tried to use 
Do

Loop Until (web1.isBusy)

But the above code does not work, So to make sure I made other form and wrote following code there

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

```
    WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://google.com")

    Do Until WebBrowser1.IsBusy

    Loop

    WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://yahoo.com")
    Do Until WebBrowser1.IsBusy

    Loop


    WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://bing.com")
    Do Until WebBrowser1.IsBusy

    Loop



    WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://facebook.com")
    Do Until WebBrowser1.IsBusy

    Loop

End Sub
```

This code directly opens the facebook.com .

I want the pages to open in series, what should i do to get pages opened in series. And whats wrong in above code

Thanks

Comment: I think you need to post a bit more code. Are you using the Facebook API? What do you mean when you say the 'logout link is activated'?

Answer (score 0):

Can you not use the [DocumentCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted.aspx) event to notify you when each page has finished loading? You can use this in combination with the [Navigating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.navigating.aspx) event to cancel or delay any further page loads if required.

Comment: Just forget about facebook project.....

Just tell me how to navigate 4-5 pages line by line....You said to use DocumentCompleted, Navigating event.....Please tell a little more, how to do that...